# Evitar que recargue un Container View al volver al controlador padre

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

tengo un controlador donde añado 4 containers view que hacen un segue a ciertos storyboards , el problema es que cuando vengo de una pantalla modal al regresar al controlador parent y entrar en el viewdidAppear , también por alguna razón me entra en los viewdidAppear de los controladores que tengo en los containers , hay alguna manera de evitar esto?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No, siempre te entrará en la función viewDidAppear de cada controlador porque forma parte del ciclo de vida de ese controlador.

Pon algo de código para hacernos una idea, o inserta un if dentro de esos viewDidAppear para comprobar si la vista ya ha sido cargada.